# Using if functions to perform calculations across two tables - Rstudio

Tags: r, excel, if-statement, calculated-columns

i'm trying to use an if function (unless there's a better way!) to convert EUR and USD amounts into GBP. I have two tables, one is of currency conversation rates, and one is of people's holiday spending.

Holiday Spending

```
Date<- c('01/01/2021', '02/01/2021','01/01/2021', '02/01/2021','01/01/2021', '02/01/2021','01/01/2021', '02/01/2021' )
Person <- c('Person A', 'Person B', 'Person C', 'Person A', 'Person B', 'Person C', 'Person A', 'Person B')
Amount <- c('100',  '150',  '200',  '250',  '300',  '350',  '400',  '450')
Currency <- c('GBP',    'EUR',  'USD',  'GBP',  'GBP',  'GBP',  'EUR',  'USD')

DF <- data.frame(Date, Person, Currency, Amount)
```

Conversation Rates

```
Date<- c('01/01/2021', '01/01/2021','02/01/2021', '02/01/2021','03/01/2021', '03/01/2021','04/01/2021', '04/01/2021' )
Country <- c('EUR', 'USD',  'EUR',  'USD',  'EUR',  'USD',  'EUR',  'USD')
Rate <- c('2',  '4',    '6',    '8',    '10',   '12',   '14',   '16')


XR <- data.frame(Date, Country, Rate)
```

What I'm looking to do is search the currency list of the holiday spending, and if the Currency column says anything not GBP, then to find the currency conversation rate of that day and re calculate the Amount column to that.

So for example, person B spend 150 Euros on the 02/10/2021, the conversation rate that day was 6 so then that 150 should be recalculated to 900, I don't need the currency column to change as it gets filtered out anyway when I rejig the tables later in the process.

I can do it in excel with vlookups and an if function, but i'm struggling to translate this to R. In Excel I have the EU and USD exchange rates on different tabs but in R it's one big table. I could split it into small tables but still not sure how to get the if and sum to work in an R format.

Excel function

```
=IF(D2="EUR",SUM(E2 * VLOOKUP(A2,EU!A:D,3,FALSE)),IF(D2="USD",SUM(E2* VLOOKUP(A2,USD!A:D,3,FALSE)),Spending!E2))
```

grateful for your advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perform a join and multiply the Rate to Amount.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  left_join(XR, by = c('Date', 'Currency' = 'Country')) %>%
  mutate(New_Amount = as.numeric(Amount) * as.numeric(Rate), 
         New_Amount = coalesce(New_Amount, as.numeric(Amount)))

#        Date   Person Currency Amount Rate New_Amount
#1 01/01/2021 Person A      GBP    100 <NA>        100
#2 02/01/2021 Person B      EUR    150    6        900
#3 01/01/2021 Person C      USD    200    4        800
#4 02/01/2021 Person A      GBP    250 <NA>        250
#5 01/01/2021 Person B      GBP    300 <NA>        300
#6 02/01/2021 Person C      GBP    350 <NA>        350
#7 01/01/2021 Person A      EUR    400    2        800
#8 02/01/2021 Person B      USD    450    8       3600
```

Comment: Another option that seems conceptually simpler to me than `coalesce` would be to set conversion factor of GBP equal to 1 before multiplying